# SubCategorization Frame of a verb

Tags: linguistics

I am working on verbal clustering. And to train my model, I need features like SCF of the verbs.

To understand what it is, I read that an SCF is a structure which gives the syntactic nature of the arguments with which the predicate can co-exist. As example, we have the sentence :

```
Alice ate chilled monkey brain
```

We see that the SCF of the verb to eat in this context is :

```
eat[NP_NP]
```

Just that, to extract these SCFs to use them as features, I don't know how it goes. Since when we talk about features x_1 ... x_n, it is necessary for each x_i, to define a value.

Clearly I don't understand the notion of SCF. Can someone clarify it for me, please.

Comment: I think Language Learning is not the appropriate forum for this post (your question is more concerned with Linguistics and computer programming / data representation). That said, you can either create a list of different SCFs, assigning an id to each (e.g. `[NP] = 1` (e.g. sleep), `[NP _NP] = 2` (eat, see, ...), `[NP _NP _NP] = 3`, ...) and then assign to each verb just a single value (the id of the SCF). Or you could see the SCF as a list of 10 values, each corresponding to a single argument, so that `eat: [NP, _NP, empty, empty, empty, ...]` etc.